# How can i cast to a class the currect class extends from

Tags: java

I'm writing a plugin and within the plugin, I am using a function to get all classes within a package. Everything works however, I cannot cast a class into a class it extends from? Shouldn't this be possible because it has all the same variables of the class it extends from.

```java
for(Class<? extends IabilityConstructor> c : findClassesImpmenenting(IabilityConstructor.class))
{
    IabilityConstructor z = (IabilityConstructor)c;

}
```

I want to cast c > z, because i cannot access the public variables the IabilityConstructor class
getting the obvious 'Cannot cast Class to IabilityConstructor'

Comment: `c` is a `Class<? extends IabilityConstructor>`, not a `IabilityConstructor`. That cast simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Does `c.newInstance()` work? Assuming `findClassesImplementing` does what its name suggests, `c.newInstance` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look on the class definition of `Class` :

```
public final class Class<T> implements java.io.Serializable,
                              GenericDeclaration,
                              Type,
                              AnnotatedElement
```

So, `Class` is never an `IabilityConstructor` hence we can't cast it.

Comment: I thought since i had the <? extnds IabilityConstructor>, that would be included. Thanks